# migrate existing rails routes/app to emberjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

i am attempting to use emberjs to render some pages within my so that the content isnt reloaded

the issue i am having is that nothing seems to be rendering

application.js

```
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require jquery.ui.all
#= require date
#= require misc
#= require foundation
#= require handlebars
#= require ember
#= require ember-data
#= require_self


App = Ember.Application.create(
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
  ready: ->
    console.log "App ready"
    return
)
App.Router.map ->
  @resource "admin/pages",
    path: "/admin/pages"

  return

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend(redirect: ->
  @transitionTo "admin/pages"
  return
)
App.NewslinksRoute = Ember.Route.extend(model: ->
  App.Page.find()
)
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen namespace: "admin/pages"
App.Store = DS.Store.extend(revision: 13)
App.Page = DS.Model.extend(name: DS.attr("string"))

# for more details see: http://emberjs.com/guides/application/
#window.Grokphoto = Ember.Application.create()
$ ->
  $(document).foundation()
  return
```

routes.rb

```
match 'admin' => 'admin/pages#index'
  namespace :admin do
    resources :events, :only => :index
    resource :photographer, :only => [:edit, :update]
    resources :pages
    resources :posts
    resources :galleries
    resources :private_galleries do
      get :invite, :on => :member
      put :send_invite, :on => :member
    end
    resources :photos, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy] do
      put 'sort', :on => :collection
    end
  end
```

then in /assets/javascripts/templates/admin/page/index.hbs i have the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="description" content="Ember - Latest" />
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Ember</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/handlebars-1.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-data-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Ember Works</h2>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

if i can just get this to render out i should be able to work the rest out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Emberjs and Rails in 2 minutes

```
rails new app
cd app

# remove gem 'coffee-rails' from Gemfile if not needed

echo "gem 'ember-rails'" >> Gemfile
echo "gem 'ember-source', '1.3.0'" >> Gemfile
bundle
rails g ember:bootstrap
rails g controller home index
(Remove the lines in the view file)

# config/routes.rb
root 'home#index'

# config/environments/development.rb
echo "Hello world" >> app/assets/javascripts/templates/index.hbs
```

`http://localhost:3000` **Voila** :)

### Rails normal flow

Here is how emberjs in Rails works. `emberjs` is just a **javascript** that can even do routing(changing urls like `/#/posts` ) .

In Rails, when a request is made to `/admin` which maps to `'admin/pages#index'` in your case will do these.

- go to the particular controller action.
- render the layout file `views/layouts/application.html.erb`
- then yield your `admin/pages#index` view inside of it.

### With Emberjs

The same thing happens when you have emberjs too, nothing special, nothing changes this order, except that you don't need anything to be render from your `admin/pages#index` view file, it can be blank.

But you need `layouts/application.html.erb` as you have all your javascript under it as

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Now the flow for `/admin`

- goes to controller action.
- renders layout file which also has javascript that also involve emberjs, along with handlebars which is again js related.
- yields your view file, which can be blank. As emberjs will insert the compiled handlebar template for us.

#### For emberjs to work in Rails.

- Your layout file needs to load javascript with your application.js.
- Then create a file `app/assets/javascripts/templates/index.hbs`

  ### Hello world

It should work! I suggest you try out creating new rails project to get some idea and tehn start migrating.

Comment: this still just renders the same erb file

Comment: Could you push your code in github or gist (routes, layouts, javascript things) to fix exactly.

Comment: Just cloned the repo. You have two application js or coffeescript file that caused the issue. 
Remove `application.js` Copy the contents of `application.js` like `#= require jquery` to `application.js.coffee`. It should work.

Better way is. Follow what i wrote, and try with a new project. Remove coffee-rails gem before installing ember, that will weed out this confusion, will update the answer too.

Comment: followed this exact and Chrome tells me I dont have an Ember app

Comment: I saw your code, you have `application.js` and `application.js.coffee`. Actually, `application.js.coffee` will compile into `application.js`, so you should copy the contents of either of the file into other and remove the other one. Your code works for me after i did that.